# How to pass this.variable to a (Angular)JS function without receiving a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my AngulsrJS code:

```
angular.module("UserApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "$location", "BaseService", function($http, $window, $location, BaseService) {

var self = this;
self.username = $location.path().substr($location.path().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

self.watch = function(self.username) {
    BaseService.watch(self.username, function() {
        // more code
    });
};
```

when I run this code, I get an error pointing to line `self.watch = function(self.username) {` and the error says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Any idea how I can pass self.username as a parameter to the function without getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove attribute from function definition  :

```
self.watch = function() {
  BaseService.watch(self.username, function() {
    // more code
});
```

};

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just realized, By the way though, why exactly am I getting an error in my case? Is it because I am defining the function this.watch and passing a this variable as a parameter when the parameter should instead be a variable which the end user decides?

Comment: what you were attempting is equivalent to 'var self.username'

Comment: With `self.watch` you are defining property with name **watch** on self object. Value of property is of type **function** (because that's what you are assign on the right side).
Talking about function definition, syntax is  `function (one,two,three)` where **one,two,three** are names of the arguments, you don't pass values here, just define names of the arguments.
In your case, you were passing values in function definition.

Answer (score 1):

function() {

will still accomplish what you want

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just realized, By the way though, why exactly am I getting an error in my case? Is it because I am defining the function `this.watch` and passing a `this` variable as a parameter when the parameter should instead be a variable which the end user decides?

Comment: its because a parameter name cannot be a dereferenced property.

Comment: hm, what exactly does dereferenced property mean? Because in my case, I define `self.username` before the function (`self.username = $location.path().substr($location.path().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`) right?

Comment: self.watch(self.username) is probably what you were thinking of. a function call is different than a function body and as such has different syntax rules

Comment: dereferenced refers to the fact that 'username' is not standalone, it is accessed via a reference to the object containing the property 'username'.

Comment: what you were attempting is equivalent to 'var self.username'